# Attempted import error: 'PrivateRoute' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I try to create a `PrivateRoute` use `react-router-dom` [like this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) and I have an ERROR like this:

```
Attempted import error: 'PrivateRoute' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
```

react: **16.12.0** 
react-router-dom: **5.1.2**

in **index.js** I am import `BrowserRoute` and use them in `ReactDOM.render()` like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and in **App.js** I render `<Home />` Component like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
```

then I Import the `PrivateRouter` from react-router-dom in `<Home />` Component like this:

```
import { 
  Switch,
  // Route,
  PrivateRoute 
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and I use `PrivateRoute` inside `render()` function like this:

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute path="/customer">
    <RootContent 
      displayContent="CUSTOMER" 
      responseCode={this.state.responseCode}
      responseStatus={this.state.responseStatus}
      responseMessage={this.state.responseMessage}
      responseData={this.state.responseData}
      getApiSuccess={this.state.getApiSuccess}
      USER_TOKEN={this.state.USER_TOKEN}
    />
  </PrivateRoute>
</Switch>
```

I still new in ReactJS. 
I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant import PrivateRoute from react-router-dom . Check the example

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";
```

In the example - PrivateRoute is a function which needs to be exported and then imported -Its not imported from react-router-dom

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: yes of course, I'm not thorough. my code goes well now, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create private route because that's not available in `react-router-dom`

Whatever `privateRoute` you see in official documentation is custom component created for private route.

Check this as an example

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```